# Why do I have to re-install HubSpot's CLI under DDEV every time it restarts?

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, hubspot, ddev

I'm working on a custom HubSpot theme for a client, making changes locally and using the HS CLI to watch and upload any changes it sees. I'm also under Windows, so I'm using DDEV under WSL 2 for the server environment.

If I go to the project directory and type:

```bash
$ ddev npm install -g @hubspot/cli
$ ddev exec hs watch my-theme my-theme
```

Everything works fine... the HS CLI monitors for changes, uploads them, and all's well.

Then when I'm done for the day, I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit the CLI, and type `ddev stop` to shut down that site.

The next day (or even immediately after), I type:

```bash
$ ddev start
$ ddev exec hs watch my-theme my-theme
```

...and get this error:

```bash
bash: line 1: hs: command not found
Failed to execute command hs watch my-theme my-theme: exit status 127
```

The only way to fix it is if I install the HubSpot CLI under DDEV *again*:

```bash
$ ddev npm install -g @hubspot/cli
```

What gives? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I should note that the entirety of the package.json is this:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@hubspot/cli": "^4.1.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're installing @hubspot/cli *globally* in the web container, so it will likely go into /usr/local, which is transient (it's created from the docker image each time the project is started).

You should instead do this in a `.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile`, so it gets built once and added onto the docker image your project uses:

```
RUN npm install -g @hubspot/cli
```

You could also install it into the project instead of installing it globally and it would persist with your project.

Docs on Dockerfile usage are at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-dockerfiles-for-webimage-and-dbimage

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The install process does take a good 30 seconds or so, so would either of those options only need to be run once? I have tried installing in non-globally, but I think it couldn't find `hs` or something.

Comment: If you use the Dockerfile approach, it persists until you delete the project, so the install only happens on the first `ddev start`